# perl - array of integers using way too much memory?

Tags: perl, types

When I run the following script:

```
my @arr = [1..5000000];

for($i=0; $i<5000000; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = $i;
        if($i % 1000000 == 0) {
                print "$i\n";
        }
}
```

It consumes about 500 MB memory. Used to higher-level compiled languages I would expect it to be roughly 5M * 4B = 20MB (4 bytes per number).

I guess that is because each value is a scalar, not a simple binary number. Is it possible to decrease memory footprint by treating those values as numbers, or is 500 MB for this task the only way?

Comment: Part of the problem is that `my @arr = [1..5000000];` is a mistake and doesn't do what you want it to. You'd probably see less usage if you wrote `my @arr = (1..5000000);`. Or simply `my @arr;` since you're not using any of the values you initialize with.

Comment: @hobbs - I made for the simplest example possible. My real script does use the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with such large arrays, you might want to use a toolkit like [the PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/).

(Oh, and yes, you are correct:  It takes so much memory because it is an array of Perl scalars.)

Answer (score 3):

All Perl values are represented internally as perl scalars, which consume *way* more memory than a simple int. Even if the scalar is only holding an int. Even if the scalar is `undef`!

As others have suggested, [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/) may be something to look at if you really want to work with huge arrays of this sort.

Comment: You need 24 bytes to store an integer value in a Perl scalar, more for a character string: http://codenode.com/perl-memory-usage/

Answer (score 3):

You can always use C or C++ in Perl.This will probably give you a small footprint in some hard jobs.
Just an idea using C!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Inline C;
use strict;

for(my $i=0; $i<5000000; $i++) {
        set_array_index($i,$i);
        if($i % 1000000 == 0) {
                #print "$i\n";
                print get_array_index($i)."\n";
        }
}

__END__
__C__

int array[5000000];

void set_array_index(int index,int value) {
    array[index]=value;
}

int get_array_index(int index) {

    if (array[index]==NULL)
        return 0;

    return array[index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete revision of my answer. Looking at what you have in your code, I see some strange things.

```
my @arr = [1..5000000];
```

Here, you assign an anonymous array-reference to `$arr[0]`. This array only holds one value: The array reference. The hidden anonymous array holds the 5 million numbers.

```
for($i=0; $i<5000000; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = $i;
        if($i % 1000000 == 0) {
                print "$i\n";
        }
}
```

Here, you fill the array with 5 million sequential numbers, overwriting the array reference in the declaration.

A much shorter way to do it would be:

```
my @arr = (1 .. 5_000_000);
```

Perhaps that will save you some memory.

Comment: `[1 .. 5_000_000]` consumes exactly as much memory whether it's a constant or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few lines from an interactive `pdl2` session showing how
this could be done using basic PDL constructs:

```
pdl> $arr = sequence(long, 5000000) + 1;  # create pdl data array (a.k.a. a piddle)

pdl> help vars                            # see, it is only ~19MB
PDL variables in package main::

Name         Type   Dimension       Flow  State          Mem
----------------------------------------------------------------
$arr           Long D [5000000]            P           19.07MB
$Pi          Double D []                   P            0.01KB

pdl> p which( $arr%1000000 == 0 )         # which returns indexes which are true
[999999 1999999 2999999 3999999 4999999]
```

See the on-line [PDL book](http://pdl.perl.org/content/pdl-book-toc.html) for
a good introduction to what PDL can be used for.
The [PDL mailing lists](http://pdl.perl.org/?page=mailing-lists) are the best
source of information on PDL usage and development.  The responses are often
rapid.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating an array, you may create a binary string that is exactly `5000000 * 4` characters long using pack:

```
my $numbers = "";
$numbers .= pack("N", $_) for (1..5000000);
```

It should definitely take less space. Consequently, you can fetch the values with `substr` and `unpack`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an iterator instead of such a big list of integers.

The iterator pays an overhead of a function call for each new value, but saves memory. Check MJD Higher Order Perl Chapter 4 ( [4.2.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=4_q8JJWNaTsC&lpg=PP1&dq=higher%20order%20perl&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q&f=false) ).

If I remember it right, range operator dont' build such a huge list in latest perls.

Answer (score 0):

Or, implicitly handling the pack for you, there is [Tie::Array::PackedC](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aPackedC):

```
use Tie::Array::PackedC;
# make @arr use $arr_storage for storing packed elements, by default using 'l!' pack format
tie my @arr, 'Tie::Array::PackedC', my $arr_storage;
```

[vec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) may also be of interest.

Comment: I have just read Tie::Array::PackedC documentation and it seems an interesting solution to keep memory usage low.