# Perl memory allocation

Tags: perl, malloc

The following simple C code allocates abouts 1.6% of my computer memory and completes in less than 2 seconds:

```
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *array = malloc(64000000);
    for (i = 0; i < 64000000; i++) {
        array[i] = i % 256;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

How can I do a similar thing in Perl?

The following Perl code consumes about 70% of my computer memory (At which I kill it)

```
my @array;
for(my $i=0;$i<64000000;$i++)
{
    $array[$i]=1;
}
getc();
exit;
```

How do I malloc in Perl ?

Comment: See [perl - array of integers using way too much memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440723/perl-array-of-integers-using-way-too-much-memory)

Comment: possibly https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec to be of help :) 

yes, I know it is a very old question but the question is important

Answer (score 4):

You allocated an array of 64,000,000 `SV*` plus 64,000,000 scalars. The array alone is already 8 times the size of what you allocated in your C program. That's not counting any of the 64,000,000 scalars or the overhead of allocating 64,000,000 memory blocks.

To allocate 64,000,000 bytes, you can use the following:

```
my $s = "\0" x 64_000_000;
```

However, that place two copies in memory.<sup>[1]</sup> The following doesn't.

```
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

my $s;
{
   open my $fh, '>', \$s;
   seek($fh, 64_000_000-1, SEEK_SET);
   print $fh "\0";
}
```

`pack`+`substr` can be used to store a number, and `substr`+`unpack` can be used to extract a number.

Finally, rather than dealing with packed numbers, you could use [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL).

---

1. Technically, it only places one copy into memory, and it does so at compile-time. Thanks to the copy-on-write (COW) mechanism, the assignment simply causes `$s` to share the buffer of the constant. But, I presume you intend to modify the buffer in `$s`, which would require making a writable copy of its buffer.

Comment: Perl has strings. Use [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to extract pieces of strings.

Comment: `Then you allocated 64,000,000 scalars` How and why second time ?

Comment: What second time? You only allocated pointers until this point.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the difference in variable sizes between languages.

See http://perlmaven.com/how-much-memory-do-perl-variables-use

This also has a good explanation of memory usage:

http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/Devel-Size-0.79/lib/Devel/Size.pm

In short, your perl array will need at least 1536 MB of space to store that array.